# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection, happens when document does not contain the indexed field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

In Mongoose I have the following `User` schema (Part of the NestJS framework):

```
@Schema()
export class User {
    @Prop({
        type: {
            idToken: { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true, sparse: true }
        },
        required: false
    })
    googleAccountData?: GoogleAccountData
    
    // Rest of properties...
}
```

As you can see, `googleAccountData` is optional in the schema, however when I create a new `User` document **without** `googleAccountData` like so:

```
const user = await this.userModel.create({
    email,
    firstName, 
    lastName
})
```

I get the following error (assuming I have 1 document without `googleAccountData`):

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: dev.users index: googleAccountData.idToken_1 dup key: { googleAccountData.idToken: null }
```

But why mongodb complains about `null` if `googleAccountData` is not even defined in the already existing document?
How can I fix this so  that the index on `googleAccountData` will be applied **only** where the field exists?

Comment: Please pass unique idToken because you have defined idToken in unique in schema

Comment: Your idToken must be unique, so if one document have a null value, you can't have another one with a null value too.
To avoid this, remove the unique index and create a compound one. Maybe email+idToken_1 or something like that. [Compound indexes doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#std-label-index-type-compound)